# On select/unselect of checkbox, query DB, return array, then update array without refresh

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, jquery-ui, codeigniter

I am currently using Jquery UI to display checkboxes, which right now, don't do anything!

you can see the current set up here: rickymason.net/letschat/main/home/

I am still trying to understand JSON, AJAX and Javascript...but i know they are required to make this work:

When the user checks one, or more of the checkboxes, I'd like it to refresh the thread list at the bottom of the page based on which list is checked.

I don't need exact code (though the more the merrier!), just a good outline on the process that needs to take place.

I'm using codeigniter, thus php and mysql.  The thread list is generated based on a * query for the threads table.  Then, it is filtered based on a session variable which contains all active filters (user input, AND i'd also like it to be selectable via the jquery select box).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic word here is `AJAX`.

- Use jQuery to bind to the events of the form elements
- Send the event through AJAX calls to the server
- Parse the response from the server and use javascript to update the page

Comment: Thanks! Its still not very clear, but with this framework, I should be able to decipher it